# Matching multiple letters across rows

Tags: r

I want to analyze my dataset in a certain way, but unfortunately, despite spending a lot of time on R, I could not figure out how to accomplish the task. Below is what I want to do:

Dataset name: Proteome (this dataset has thousands of rows and 14 columns: below I am showing only four entries in column 5)

```
Row 1, column 5: GHFCLKPGCNFHAESTRGYR
Row 2, column 5: FCLKPGCNFHAESTRGYR
Row 3, column 5: GHFCLKPGCNFHAESTR
Row 4: column 5: GCNFHAESTR
```

In row 2, first two letters of row 1 are missing; 
in row 3, last three letters of row 1 are missing; 
in row 4, first seven and last three letters of row 1 are missing.

Rows 2, 3, and 4 reflect the artifacts of the scientific method I have been using to generate the data, and therefore I want to remove these entries.

Ideally, I want R to return me the top entry, but it would be OK if R could only collapse such rows into a single row. My idea is to collapse multiple rows into one if five consecutive letters in those rows match with each other. In the above example, GCNFHAESTR match in all four rows, so I want R to return me only one row, ideally the top one.

Comment: indeed, it will help if you can provide some example rows that don't match with row 4. How many rows your dataset have ?

Comment: Have you done any searching with google looking for alignment methods using package from BioConductor?

Comment: @d.b the code returned the following:

structure(c(4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), .Label = c("FCLKPGCNFHAESTRGYR", 
"GCNFHAESTR", "GHFCLKPGCNFHAESTR", "GHFCLKPGCNFHAESTRGYR"), class = "factor")

Comment: @demarsylvain My dataset has around 6000 rows. This is the first time I have posted a question on this forum. Could anyone please guide me how I can show the image of my data frame. I tried to paste the screenshot, but that also didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Please check out a part of my data frame here (if this doesn't work, please copy paste the URL to a new page):
http://i67.tinypic.com/2wd0ap3.png[/IMG]